# Sort a list with but with pre-determined override values using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

The business problem is a bit obtuse so I won't get into the details.

I have to come up with a sort index for a set of keys, but some of those keys have a pre-determined position in the index which must be respected.  The remaining keys have to be ordered as normal but "around" the pre-determined ones.

Simple example is to sort the letters A through E, except that A must be position 3 and D must be position 1.  The result I want to achieve is:

```
A: 3 B: 2 C: 4 D: 1 E: 5
```

DDL to set up sample:

```
CREATE TABLE test.element (element_key TEXT, override_sort_idx INTEGER);

insert into test.element VALUES ('A', 3), ('B', Null), ('C', NULL), ('D', 1), ('E', NULL);
```

The best solution I can come up with is this, but although it appears to work for this simple example, it goes wrong in the general case - it falls apart if you add some more pre-defined values [EDIT - it doesn't even work in this example because A comes out as 4 - apologies]:

```
WITH inner_sort AS (SELECT element_key, override_sort_idx, row_number()
OVER (ORDER BY element_key) AS natural_sort_idx
              FROM test.element)
SELECT element_key, row_number()
    OVER
     (ORDER BY
      CASE
      WHEN override_sort_idx IS NULL
      THEN natural_sort_idx
      ELSE override_sort_idx END) AS hybrid_sort
FROM inner_sort;
```

Any ideas for a solution that works in the general case?

Comment: This would give element_key 'A' with  override_sort_idx = 3 the hybrid_sort = 4 ?

Comment: Yes I think my solution's rubbish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proved to be more of a challenge that I initially expected.

But this SQL returns the expected results:

```
WITH OPENNUMBERS AS
(
  select row_number() over () as num
  from test.element 
  except
  select override_sort_idx
  from test.element 
  where override_sort_idx is not null
)
, OPENNUMBERS2 AS
(
  select num, row_number() over (order by num) as rn
  from OPENNUMBERS
)
,NORMALS AS
(
    select element_key, row_number() over (order by element_key) as rn
    from test.element
    where override_sort_idx is null
)
select n.element_key, o.num as hybrid_sort_idx
from OPENNUMBERS2 o
join NORMALS n ON n.rn = o.rn 
union all
select element_key, override_sort_idx
from test.element  
where override_sort_idx is not null
order by hybrid_sort_idx;
```

You can test it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/95960/4/0) on SQL Fiddle.

The trick used?
Get a list of index numbers that are still free after you remove the overriden. (using EXCEPT)
Then get a row_number for those numbers and also for the non-overridden. 
Join those on the rownumber.
Then stich the overridden to it.

Comment: I desperately wanted this to work!  But I added some more values to the table that skip elements and also add a index value that goes beyond the natural range (which arguably distorts the original problem as stated).  My full set is now ('A' 3), ('B', NULL), ('C', NULL), ('D', 1), ('E', NULL), ('G', 12), ('H', 4), ('I', NULL), ('J', NULL), ('K', NULL), ('L', NULL).  Your query gives C as 4, H as 5, G as 11.  I have written something I'm too embarrassed to post with five nested CTEs, a UNION and an EXCEPT, which takes the non-predetermined keys, "remaining" index values, stitches, unions back..

Comment: @enjayaitch I'll have a look at after dinner.  By then maybe someone else found an even nicer solution. It's a bit of a special puzzle. Btw, you should tag the database type you are using. DBMS's often have specific tricks that aren't ANSI SQL.

Comment: @enjayaitch Updated. Now it also works with the larger sample. Was harder to pull off than I thought it would be. Tried with cumulative sums and the lot. But in the end, it turned out similar to your method. I.e. Getting the remaining indexes, then do something with that.

Comment: definitely better than mine (easier to read, less redundancy, better explain).   Really felt like this should be a three-line, one window function job - I'm quite pleased I'm not the only one not to find that solution!  Thanks very much.  Like your site, by the way.

Comment: I think the `ORDER BY override_sort_idx` in the `row_number()` function in the `OPENNUMBERS` query is not required.  Seemingly trivial but as I'm now applying this to my real data and business problem the difference in the explain is quite noticeable.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I didn't think it would make much difference in performance. And in other databases like MS Sql Server the ORDER BY is mandatory. So that's why it was added.  But it seems not to be the case in postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this since it works, and I think it's the best I can do, but it's pretty horrific.

```
WITH grouped AS (
   SELECT element_key, override_sort_idx, 
          row_number() OVER (
                             PARTITION BY override_sort_idx IS NULL
                             ORDER BY override_sort_idx, element_key) 
                                                        AS group_idx,
          row_number() OVER (ORDER BY element_key)      AS natural_sort_idx
    FROM test.element),
 remaining_idx AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER () AS remain_idx FROM test.element
    EXCEPT
    SELECT override_sort_idx FROM test.element),
 indexed_remaining AS (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY remain_idx) AS r_sort_idx, 
           remain_idx 
    FROM remaining_idx)
SELECT g.element_key, 
       coalesce(g.override_sort_idx, r.remain_idx) AS hybrid_index
FROM grouped g
LEFT JOIN indexed_remaining r ON 
     (CASE WHEN g.override_sort_idx IS NULL 
           THEN g.group_idx END = r.r_sort_idx)
ORDER BY hybrid_index
```

This involves creating the "remaining" index values first as the difference between a simple row_number() and the pre-determined index values, which is then joined to a sorted list of keys without pre-determined index values.

The `CASE` statement in the JOIN is functionally unnecessary given the order of the coalesce but it seems like the "purer" approach.

I have a feeling that someone smarter than me, who understands window functions properly, could write this using window functions with filters, or manipulating the range of a window function, without the crazy nested subqueries/CTEs and joins.